# Scrapy chain selector with different parents

Tags: css, python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I want to chain two selectors together that have different parents.  The selector I'm using currently:

```
..css('td:nth-child(8) > span.cap.mtv > ::text')
```

Which yields:

`<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::td[count(preceding-sibling::*) = 7]/span[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' cap ') and (@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' mtv '))]/*/text()" data='$725,000'>`

The issue I have is that I also want the following:

```
..xpath('td[8]/div/text()')
```

Which yields:

`<Selector xpath='td[8]/div/text()' data='UFA'>`

Ultimately I want to use an item loader and extract to get:

`$725,000
UFA
...`

I want to achieve something similar to the following..

`...xpath('td[8]').css('span.cap.mtv > ::text').xpath('/div/text()')`

I have previously just sort of re-scraped an element w/ another set of selectors if the program had previously found nothing but would much rather have this sort of 'either/or' flexibility.  Or would I be better of looking at another selector all together for this situation?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using item loaders, you can simply add multiple selectors for a single field as shown in  [scrapy docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#using-item-loaders-to-populate-items).

Something like this should work, after creating a loader:

```
loader.add_css('field', 'td:nth-child(8) > span.cap.mtv > ::text')
loader.add_xpath('field', 'td[8]/div/text()')
```

Your input/output processors would then be responsible for how this information is combined.

Comment: I've used this approach before for something similar and it worked out well; maybe I should try this again... I was looking for something a little less verbose